# Angular 12 Data table not showing data until i use modal

Tags: angular, spring, crud

I have an "error", if in my **menu.component.ts** i dont add this.getEmployee(1); on my **ngOnInit()** , the table looks empty until i press edit button and then suddenly all the information appears on the table. I don't want to use that "bad smell code" so i want to know what am i doing wrong.

Thanks

**menu.component.html**

```
<table class="table table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">ID</th>
                                <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
                                <th scope="col">Apellido</th>
                                <th scope="col">Estado</th>
                                <th scope="col">Acciones</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr *ngFor="let employee of employees">
                                <td><span>{{employee.id}}</span></td>
                                <td><span>{{employee.nombre}}</span></td>
                                <td><span>{{employee.apellidos}}</span></td>
                                <td><span>{{employee.employeeStatus}}</span></td>
                                <td>
                                    <button (click)="getEmployee(employee.id)" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#editModal"><i class="material-icons">edit</i>Editar</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="material-icons">delete_outline</i>Eliminar</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

And the function code in **menu.component.ts**

```
getEmployee(id: number){
this.httpClient.get<any>('http://localhost:8080/employee/get/'+id).subscribe(
  employeeResponse => {
    console.log(employeeResponse);
    this.em = employeeResponse;
  }
);
```

}

**API REST**

public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService {

```
private final EmployeeRepo employeeRepo;

/**
 * Creamos un empleado con lo que hemos recibido por metodo POST en el JSON.
 * @param employee
 * @return
 */
@Override
public Employee create(Employee employee) {
    log.info("Saving the employee: {" + employee.getNombre() + ":" + employee.getId() + "}");
    return employeeRepo.save(employee);
}

/**
 * Obtener el empleado en funcion de su ID.
 * @param id
 * @return
 */
@Override
public Employee get(Long id) {
    log.info("Fetching employee by ID {" + id + "}");
    return employeeRepo.findById(id).get();
}

/**
 * Actualizamos un empleado con la nueva informacion.
 * @param employee
 * @return
 */
@Override
public Employee update(Employee employee) {
    log.info("Updating employee: {}", employee.getNombre());
    return employeeRepo.save(employee);
}

@Override
public Boolean delete(Long id) {
    employeeRepo.deleteById(id);
    return true;
}

@Override
public Collection<Employee> list() {
    return employeeRepo.findAll();
}

@Override
public List<Employee> getAllEmployee() {
    return employeeRepo.findAll();
}
```

}

Comment: Share component code along with API response payload

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are looping through employees which is empty on init so the table shows no data. Is there an API which returns the full employee list rather than only based on ids? If there is you can populate the table on init using that API call.

Comment: Yes, i have a method for geting all the employees and a method for getting employee by an ID. When i implemented only the first method (populate the datatable) it was working fine, then i implemented the second method (edit option loading user details) and it stopeed updating it

Comment: Is the edit button just supposed to open a modal? Please post a stackblitz

Comment: Yes, the edit button opens a modal, i tried removing the edit button and the error persists, it justs stops when i remove the function